# using radio button inside ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to use `Radio button` inside `ng-repeat`.
I have done the following. With this code, i am able to select option button for the 1st repeat but not for the further repeats.The radio buttons are disabled for further repeats...

Probably, I would like to know how i can use radio button inside ng-repeat.

```
<div ng-repeat="student in Entities.Students">
<div class="form-group col-lg-12 col-sm-8">
<label class="col-lg-2 control-label">Student </label>
<div class="button-holder col-lg-2">
    <input type="radio" class="regular-radio" id="male" data-ng-model="student.Gender" value="Male" />
    <label for="male">
        <span class="Radiobox-txt">Male</span>
    </label>
</div>
<div class="button-holder col-lg-2">
    <input type="radio" class="regular-radio" id="female" data-ng-model="student.Gender" value="Female" />
    <label for="male">
        <span class="Radiobox-txt">Female</span>
    </label>
</div>
</div>
```

This is how i am expecting data returned from server

```
Entities = 
{
    Students:[
                {Name: 'One',Gender: 'Male'},
                {Name: 'Two',Gender: 'Female'},
                {Name: 'Three',Gender: 'Male'},
                {Name: 'Four',Gender: 'Female'}
            ]
};
```

Comment: Just a quick note, should it be `<div ng-repeat="student in Entities.Students">` with an "s" after "Student" to match the return data from server?

Comment: Yes, it should be. I updated my question

Comment: While I don't exactly know why, it sounds like the version of Angular and availability of a directive library such as Angular-ui Bootstrap is having an effect on the output. Using versions of Angular less than 1.3 and some version of ui-bootstrap, your radio buttons all output. If I remove ui-bootstrap, only one radio button set displays. Here is a plunker demonstrating the functionality. Maybe this will help you identify the issues. [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ANX4fmw9VBzO3T0oGhGx?p=preview)

Comment: Well thanks you for your effort.  it looks fine but i have question .. Why you did not use $index+$parent.$index for Id and Label for to differentiate radio buttons Otherwise else, clicking on one radio button selects other radio button in my code and i made it ok by using $index+$parent.$index for Id and Label.. Hope you get my point?

Comment: It's working for me. [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/mllUAR8d3A8LPiUd3tVG?p=preview). I noticed you are missing a close div tag. Could that be it? Can you provide a Plunkr of the issue? Another thing that's work noting is id should be unique and in this case it won't be.

Comment: Yes it is even working for me but i wonder how did you make each option radio button unique? If i inspect any radio button i see 'Name' property with unique value.. Do you know from where that value coming because you did not set in code.